# post multiple variables with javascript load

Tags: javascript, variables, post, load

I want to post some variables with the load function. the code just like this.

```
var database = "<?php echo $db;?>";
var table = "<?php echo $table;?>";
var formdata = "&dbname="+database+"&tablename="+table;
var track_click = 0; //track user click on "load more" button, righ now it is 0 click
$('#results').load("showdataprocess.php", {'page':track_click , formdata }, function() 
{track_click++;});
```

and, it doesn't work. Any idea how? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to post some variables with the load function...

Yes, you can do that. If you supply an object to `load` as its second argument, `load` uses HTTP `POST` rather than HTTP `GET`.

> ...and it doesn't work.

And if you look in the web console, you'll see an error pointing out the syntax error

```js
$('#results').load("showdataprocess.php", {'page':track_click , formdata }, function() 
{track_click++;}); //                                                   ^
// Here ----------------------------------------------------------------/
```

You either pass a string or an object. In your case, the easiest thing (which also encodes things correctly) is to get rid of your `formdata` variable entirely and put all three pieces of information in an object you pass as the second argument:

```js
var database = "<?php echo $db;?>";
var table = "<?php echo $table;?>";
var track_click = 0; //track user click on "load more" button, righ now it is 0 click
$('#results').load("showdataprocess.php", {
    page: track_click,
    dbname: database,
    tablename: table
}, function () {
    track_click++;
});
```

Then access those on the `$_POST` object, e.g.:

```php
$dbname = $_POST["dbname"];
```

---

**But**: Unless you have a really, really good reason, **don't** send information about your database to the *client*! That exposes too much of your infrastructure. Hold that information server-side, don't send it to the client and have the client send it back.

Comment: i have tried using `echo$_GET['tablename'];
echo $_GET['page'];
echo $_GET['dbname'];` to check, but it's returning this error meassage.  "Notice: Undefined index: tablename in D:\xampp\htdocs\rts3\sgcdm\mudjiono\showdataprocess.php on line 155" is there another way to retrieve the value?

Comment: @user3615709: My mistake, if you pass an object to `load` as its second argument, it does a `POST`, not a `GET`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix key/value string data with an object for `.load()`. Change to pass all of the data in the object.

```
$('#results').load("showdataprocess.php", {'page':track_click , dbname : database, tablename : table}, function()
```

It's possible to pass a string as the whole data, but `.load()` will do a GET request instead of POST.